# Pass ID from view of type IEnumerable using HTML Actionlink in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two models "Computer" and "Computer Detail." From the Computer's Index page the user can click "View Details" for a given record which redirects to the Index of the Computer Detail and fetches all the records associated with that given "Computer ID" using the query string - That works fine

My problem is I want to have a "Create" link that carries this "Computer ID" (shown in view) and populates the Computer ID field on the Create form.

I used *Model.First().ComputerID* that worked to run the code with some test records but of course it doesn't work if records for the ComputerID is null.

**View**

```
@modelIEnumerable<MyApp.Models.ComputerDetail>
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2 class ="page-header">Computer Details</h2>

 <div class ="col-lg-12">
     <p>
           @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "ComputerDetail", new {id = Model.First().ComputerID}, new { @class = "btn btn-default"})
     </p>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class ="panel-body">
        <table class ="table table-striped" id="dtaTable">
            <thead class ="dataTableHead">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ComputerID)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
                    </th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
               </tr>
        </thead>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ComputerID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.FullName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
                    </td>
                </tr>
}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var _FindComputerID = GetComputerDetails(id);
        return View(_FindComputerID);
    }

    private List<ComputerDetail>GetComputerDetails(int id)
    {
        var FindComputerID = db.ComputerDetails.Where(cd => cd.ComputerID == id).Include
                    (cd => cd.Employee).OrderByDescending(cd => cd.ID);

        return FindComputerID.ToList();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ComputerDetail computerdetail = new ComputerDetail ();
        computerdetail.ComputerID = id;

        return View(computerdetail);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class ComputerDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter service tag")]
    [Display(Name = "Service Tag")]
    public int ComputerID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select employee name")]
    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter date")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Bought")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Bought")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    //references
    public virtual Assets.Computer Computer { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Create method in controller accept int which is not nullable type. Obviously, if a null value is passed then controller will throw error.

Comment: What is the question ? You already describe what will happen if  ComputerID is null.

Comment: What I want is to access the model properties directly. From the ienumerable view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thing are happening here:

In the first place, if your view needs to get the ComputerID you may want to reflect this field in the ViewModel and not magically get it from the first item in the list.

```
public class ComputerDetailsViewModel
{
    public int ComputerID {get; set;} // populate in the action directly
    public IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.ComputerDetail> Items {get; set;}
}
```

You really want to go that route, you should use the nullable operator for better error handling figure it out what happens when the ComputerID is null.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "ComputerDetail", new {id = Model.FirstOrDefault()?.ComputerID ?? 0 /*Null case*/}, new { @class = "btn btn-default"})
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i see things more clearly now.